# TPS61200 gets really hot

Tags: circuit-analysis, battery-charging, boost

I have a problem with a battery booster/charger circuit, that I really can't figure out and I hope that somebody can help me.

This is the circuit:[image]

When i connect a 3,7V battery at  X3-2 and X3-2 the TPS61200 quickly gets very hot. However it is still working and outputting 5V. At the moment the TPS output is not connected to anything.

There is no USB connected to the USB-POWER supply.

The circuit is based on the following schematic:
http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Prototyping/PowerCell-v13.pdf

Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

UPDATE 1:
I meassured the 5V output with an oscilloscope and got the following result:
[image]
It seems like the TPS cuts off repeatedly (maybe because of internal thermometer?). It cuts off at 5.8V, and drops down somewhere between 1-2V.

I also meassured while driving a DC motor and got a similar result:
[image]

Here is the PCB-layout from eagle:
Top
[image]

Bottom
[image]

I have also taken some pictures of the board:
Top
[image]

Bottom
[image]

Comment: How much current are you pulling (trying to pull) on the 5V?

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the actual (built) circuit (possibly both sides of the PCB). Moreover, can you probe the 5V output with an oscilloscope? Maybe there is an high frequency oscillation superimposed to the 5V output.

Comment: How much copper is connected to the bottom-side exposed circuit pad of IC1?

Comment: What inductor did you use?

Comment: Have you checked 5V output with an oscilloscope?  Some converters require a minimum load for stability.  If you add a small load on 5V, say 10% of full load, does it get better?

Comment: @Tyler I am currently meassuring a very low current. The 5v is supposed to power two motors and a couple of ATmegas.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Please see update 1. I have uploaded some pictures and layouts.

Comment: @AdamLawrence Please see the layouts that I uploaded in update 1.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have used the following inductor:
http://www.kosmodrom.com.ua/pdf/CDRH2D09.pdf

Comment: @scorpdaddy I have uploaded the oscilloscope results in update 1. A load does not make it better.

Comment: You have hidden the outer part of the board, is there actually continuity across the bottom ground pour from right to left- 'cause it's not visible.

Comment: In the lo-load scope trace, how is C10 getting drained so quickly?  Is it really zero load?  Could IC1 have been fried in a prior test?  Have you tried replacing IC1?

Comment: The part also has a down mode: "If the input voltage reaches or exceeds the output voltage, the converter automatically changes to a Down
Conversion mode. In this mode, the control circuit changes the behavior of the two rectifying switches. While
continuing switching, it sets the voltage drop across the rectifying switches as high as needed to regulate the
output voltage. This means the power losses in the converter increase. This must be taken into account for
thermal consideration."  Would explain why it gets hot.  It's discharging C10 through IC1.

Comment: You may be able to improve stability with a 100nF cap across R2.  100nF might be the wrong size.  Could be a smaller value that gets the stability balance.  Might start with 10 nF and work up.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes there is continuity. Sorry, I may have simplified the board a little too much.

Comment: @scorpdaddy I have tried replacing the entire board, so I dont think it's due to a bad IC.

I am not sure I understand completely. Why would the input voltage exceed the output voltage in the first place?

Comment: In that case, it is likely the down-regulation feature engaging.  You may be able to stabilize it with a capacitor across R2, say 100nF.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the layout of your board differs so brutally from manufacturer's recommended layout?

Answer (score 1):

In looking at your layout, you don't have a great thermal ground connection and are doubling your thermal resistance (Junction-to-board characterization parameter 16.8 C/W, if I read right which also happens to be the lowest thermal resistance pathway to the ambient) to the ground plane by halving the connections to it. And not having as much ground plane to sink current also presents an issue. The layout guideline in the datasheet has the ground connected on both sides. A quick look to the datasheet also suggests as well as other issues with this design:

> If the layout is not carefully done, the regulator could show
>   stability problems as well as EMI problems. Therefore, use wide and
>   short traces for the main current path and for the power ground
>   tracks. The input and output capacitor, as well as the inductor should
>   be placed as close as possible to the IC. Use a common ground node for
>   power ground and a different one for control ground to minimize the
>   effects of ground noise. Connect these ground nodes at any place close
>   to one of the ground pins of the IC.

It also looks like the inductor is located far away from the IC which probably isn't that big of a deal, but the cap C11 could be a big issue. You have a small trace from the battery to the power cap and from the power cap to the TPS61200, these traces have parasitic resistance and inductance. This parasitic impedance blocks the effectiveness of C11 and also makes it harder to source power from the battery at high frequencies. At this point I would consider scrapping this design and making it more like the manufacturers suggestion.

You could run through the power equations and throw in parasitic resistances and inductance and see what your biggest source of thermal error is. Simulating it in spice always helps too, and the parasitic resistances and inductances can be calculated from PCB trace calculators.  One thing that you could do is beef up the traces to C11 with a blue wire and see if this helps on your current design.

Short story, follow the manufacturers lead on these, or do lots of math, but it usually takes less design time to just go with the manufacturers tested solution. Sometimes you can get away with layouts like this if your not generating a lot of heat in the switcher.